# Canvas auto running on off window click?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Canvas auto runs when you click on another window and come back.

I have added key listeners and they make the ship move when you click `w` `a` `s` `d` or `up`, `left`, `right`, `down`.

It all works fine until you click two buttons like up and right and then click on another tab or window and come back. Then it will just keep moving not listening to your input.

What I think the problem is, is that when you click off the page the canvas never gets to check if the key was left up.But how do I make all the keys act like they were unpressed when you click off the screen?
Also the enemy disappera when you move off screen
This is what happens when buttons are pressed:

```
Player.prototype.checkKeys = function() //these functions are in the PLayer class
{


    if(this.isUpKey == true)//if true 
{
    if(Player1.drawY >= 0)
  {
 this.drawY -= this.Speed; 
  }
}

if(this.isRightKey == true)
{

 if(Player1.drawX <= (canvasWidthShips - this.playerWidth))
  {
  this.drawX += this.Speed;
  }
}

if(this.isDownKey == true)
{
  if(Player1.drawY <= (canvasHeightShips - this.playerHeight))
  {
  this.drawY += this.Speed;
  }
}

if(this.isLeftKey == true)
{
if(Player1.drawX >= 0)
 {
  this.drawX -= this.Speed;
  }
}
};
```

And these are my simple functions to check when a key is pressed down, I dont think the error is here but not sure?

```
 function checkKeyDown(e)
{
if (Paused == false)
  {
 var KeyID = e.KeyCode || e.which;
if (KeyID === 38 || KeyID === 87)  //up and w keyboard buttons
  {

 Player1.isUpKey = true;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

}

if (KeyID === 39 || KeyID === 68)  //right and d keyboard buttons
{

Player1.isRightKey = true;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

 }

  if (KeyID === 40 || KeyID === 83)  //down and s keyboard buttons
 {

 Player1.isDownKey = true;
 e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

 }

if (KeyID === 37 || KeyID === 65)  //left and a keyboard buttons
{

 Player1.isLeftKey = true;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

 }

 }

 else if (Paused == true)
 {
 Player1.isUpKey = false;
 Player1.isDownKey = false;
 Player1.isRightKey = false;
 Player1.isLeftKey = false;

 }

 }

function checkKeyUp(e)
{


if (Paused == false)
  {
 var KeyID = e.KeyCode || e.which;
if (KeyID === 38 || KeyID === 87)  //up and w keyboard buttons
  {

  Player1.isUpKey = false;
  e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing


 }

 if (KeyID === 39 || KeyID === 68)  //right and d keyboard buttons
 {

 Player1.isRightKey = false;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

}

if (KeyID === 40 || KeyID === 83)  //down and s keyboard buttons
{

 Player1.isDownKey = false;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

}

if (KeyID === 37 || KeyID === 65)  //left and a keyboard buttons
{

Player1.isLeftKey = false;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

}

}

else if (Paused == true)
 {
 Player1.isUpKey = false;
 Player1.isDownKey = false;
 Player1.isRightKey = false;
 Player1.isLeftKey = false;

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be ok to just pause the game? You can listen for [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onblur) on the browser window which gets triggered when it loses focus and then just pause the game in the event handler.

```
window.onblur = function() {
                // Add logic to pause the game here...
                Paused = true;
            };
```

Comment: This works however how can I un-pause it I dont want to have to click on the canvas to resume? Is there a window not onblur?

Comment: Yes, there is: `window.onfocus` is the opposite of `window.onblur`